# Virtualbox on OSX not showing VT-x/AMD-V option

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I just set up my new Macbook Pro 15" (2017). During the installation and configuration of my Virtualbox VM's I realised, that the "Enable VT-x/AMD-V" option which can be found under Virtual Machine Settings - System - Acceleration is not available on my new Macbook Pro while it was on my previous one (Macbook Pro 15" 2014). Do you have any ideas what might be the reason for that? Both of the Macbooks are running under macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and they both have the latest version of VirtualBox installed. Since I am doing a lot of work in VM's I would be really happy to be able to enable this option.

Would appreciate it a lot if someone could help me.

Regards

Answer (score 5):

It seems the option does not show up in VirtualBox any more. However, the "Acceleration" details do show up on the VirtualBox dashboard screen on the right, under the System details.

In my case (on Mac), when "default" paravirtualization-interface option is selected (under Acceleration tab), the VB dashboard shows VT-x to be enabled.

[image]

Comment: How do you disable the *VT-x/AMD-V* option? It still does not show up on OSX to this day. Changing any of the "Paravirtualization Interfac" options and/or disabling "Hardware Virtualization" by unchecking "Enabled Nested Paging" do not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal list all VMs with

```
vboxmanage list vms
```

Find yours and then

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "Your_name_2004" --nested-hw-virt on
```